# How can I redirect welcome.jsp to login.jsp?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am making this application using Java, Struts2 and Hibernate. 
Now what I want to implement is that whenever I directly type `localhost:8080/TwitterClone/welcome.jsp` it should be redirected to `localhost:8080/TwitterClone/login.jsp` if the user is not logged in. What would be the most efficient way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void init() {

}

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation)
        throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();

    User user = (User) sessionAttributes.get("user");

    if(user == null){
        return Action.LOGIN;
    }else{
        Action action = (Action) actionInvocation.getAction();
        if(action instanceof UserAware){
            ((UserAware) action).setUser(user);
        }
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
}

}
```

You can implement Interceptor. But for that you need write mapping in your struts.xml file too

[You can refer  link](http://www.journaldev.com/2210/struts-2-interceptor-tutorial-with-custom-authentication-interceptor-example)